# UI-Grid Angularjs, get the sorted fields?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angular-ui-grid

I have found this option for ng-grid ==> getSortModel(), but not for 
http://ui-grid.info/.

Anyone has an idea on how to get these values from the grid and nog using jquery or some custom javascript to actually get the values in the column header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i know is: iterate over all columns, getting filters:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.forEach(function (c) {
var term = c.filter.term
}
```

Comment: Thats the way I was thinking to get the filter. But this is different from the sort function, no? Like asc, desc, "". It looks like only the filter value is updated when something changes in the data-grid.

Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Oops, sorry, i was thinking , you need to get filters.  I was using the feature, that i am getting sort setting on sortChanged event: gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) { var sorting = sortColumns}